# C#: Convert Dictionary<> to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, namevaluecollection

How can I convert a `Dictionary<string, string>` to a `NameValueCollection`?

The existing functionality of our project returns an old-fashioned `NameValueCollection` which I modify with LINQ. The result should be passed on as a `NameValueCollection`.

I want to solve this in a generic way. Any hints?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Why not use a simple `foreach` loop?

```
foreach(var kvp in dict)
{
    nameValueCollection.Add(kvp.Key.ToString(), kvp.Value.ToString());
}
```

This could be embedded into an extension method:

```
public static NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection<TKey, TValue>(
    this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
{
    var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();

    foreach(var kvp in dict)
    {
        string value = null;
        if(kvp.Value != null)
            value = kvp.Value.ToString();

        nameValueCollection.Add(kvp.Key.ToString(), value);
    }

    return nameValueCollection;
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
var nameValueCollection = dict.ToNameValueCollection();
```

Comment: Lol, forgot about this. Thank generics for this!

Comment: This code can throw [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx)s, because the `kvp.Value` could be `null`. If this is the case, just add the `null` value to the `NameValueCollection`.

Answer (score 41):

And if you like LINQ:

### Dictionary to NameValueCollection

```
return dictionary.Aggregate(new NameValueCollection(),
    (seed, current) => { 
        seed.Add(current.Key, current.Value);
        return seed;
    });
```

### NameValueCollection to Dictionary

([source](http://ohcsharp.blogspot.com/2011/11/convert-namevaluecollection-to.html))

```
return source.Cast<string>()  
    .ToDictionary(s => s, s => source[s]);
```

Comment: updated -- simplified NVC->Dict (don't need intermediary select...)

Comment: Been hunting for this answer on SO all morning. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

try this Extension to Dictionary I hope it's what you wanted:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static NameValueCollection ToNameValueCollection<tValue>(this IDictionary<string, tValue> dictionary)
    {
        var collection = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach(var pair in dictionary)
            collection.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value.ToString());
        return collection;
    }
}
```

use like

```
var nvc = myDict.ToNameValueCollection();
```

note: I have constrained the key to be string because I didn't want to overgeneralize - of course you can change this with a generic type and .ToString() for the key too.