# The most 'elegant' way to populate a Dictionary<String,String> from a delimited string

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, split

I think those with even a slight grasp on basic string manipulation, loops and dictionaries can work out how to populate a Dictionary from a String such as this:

**Black:#00000|Green:#008000|** *(where "Black" is the Key and "#000000" is the Value)*

But what is the most 'elegant' way of doing it in your opinion? What is the most efficient/more concise coding I can use to achieve it? So far I have:

```
    public static Dictionary<String, String> ThemeColors
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<String, String> themeColors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (String colorAndCode in GetSettingByName("ThemeColors").ToString().Split('|'))
            {
                themeColors.Add(colorAndCode.Split(':').First(), colorAndCode.Split(':').Last());
            }
            return themeColors;
        }
    }
```

GetSettingByName("ThemeColours") returns the string above (in Bold).

It's functional obviously, it all works, but I want to make sure I'm beginning to think beyond this now and working out the best way of doing things rather than just getting it working.

Can I use a yield on the Dictionary loop for example??

Comment: Why go through the work of splitting by : twice?

Comment: When I'm adding to themeColors you mean?

Comment: Yeah, split once into an array, and then call First and Last on that array.

Comment: and you have an error if there is an trailing `|` in the input, you should use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` in the first split (foreach loop)

Comment: Up votes for both of you. Thanks a lot, changes have been made.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this bacause as it's readable and quite fast.
The only things you can do it's to split only once the string as suggested by @carl

Comment: I'd put `colorAndCode.Split(':')` in a variable so you don't have to execute it twice

Comment: Have a look at this [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306767/linq-to-convert-a-string-to-a-dictionarystring-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually like a slight variant of your approach best:

```
    public static Dictionary<String, String> ThemeColors
    {
        get
        {
            Dictionary<String, String> themeColors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (String colorAndCode in GetSettingByName("ThemeColors").ToString().Split('|'))
            {
                var parts = colorAndCode.Split(':');
                themeColors.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
            return themeColors;
        }
    }
```

The only difference is that the second `Split()` is done only once, and direct indexing is rather than `First()` and `Last()`.

Now `ToDictionary()` is great when it makes sense to include something in a wider query, and I certainly wouldn't consider it wrong, but it's not like your approach is particularly verbose or anything.

But I like that it's easy to change your approach to tolerate duplicates (use `dict[parts[0]] = parts[1]` and it'll over-write duplicates rather than throwing), but it's also easy to change to throw for `Black:#00000:#010101` by testing the size of `parts`.

In the other direction, if you've a need to get as quick a parsing of a massive string as possible, then throw elegance out the window and replace it with something that scans throught the string tokenising by `|` rather than using `Split()`.

Meanwhile, the above fits a nice middle-ground between concision and precision.

Answer (score 8):

```
 public static Dictionary<String, String> ThemeColors
    {
        get
        {
           return GetSettingByName("ThemeColors").ToString().Split('|').ToDictionary(colorAndCode => colorAndCode.Split(':').First(), colorAndCode => colorAndCode.Split(':').Last());
        }
    }
```

As suggested in comments more elegant way

```
 public static Dictionary<String, String> ThemeColors2
        {
            get
            {
                return GetSettingByName("ThemeColors").ToString().Split('|').Select(x => x.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2)).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ahh, I've never even noticed the ToDictionary extension to be honest. Thanks a LOT!

Comment: I'd have done `.Select(x=>x.Split(new[]{':'},2)).ToDictionary(x=>x[0],x=>x[1])`

Comment: I think this solution is less readable and much slower then the solution that uses the foreach.

Comment: Without being bias - I would have to agree mine is more readable. I think that's obvious, but in terms of speed and efficiency I think Haris' answer is definitely an improvement.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso Slower, it's impossible to tell without measuring. I don't see *why* it would be any slower than the current solution. We could get a slight "boost" by not splitting on `:` twice using `Select`, but this is how I'd have done it. For people familiar with LINQ this is very readable.

Comment: You should use `Split(new[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` to avoid errors.

Comment: LINQ is always slower than a foreach(Linq to object uses For behind the scene)
Refactoring the code splitting only once it would be enought. I think sometime people over-use LINQ just because is cool without caring about performances

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso you are right but in most of the cases this slowness it would cause won't really matter. This phenomena is called premature optimizations

Comment: in this case I don't see a reason to use LINQ which is much less readable than the solution using the classic ForEach :LINQ should be used to improve the readability or when what we are doing would be to complex to achieve with classic for +
it is not possible to debug the LINQ solution
We can't talk about "premature optimizations" in this case

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative that uses a foreach. The answers by @Haris Hasan and @vcsjones are elegant in their own right. The reason I show this is that I encapsulate this logic in a static StringHelper class and this method can then be used as an extension of string.

The code from either answer above could be incorporated into this method.

Calling example:

```
var str = "Black:#00000|Green:#008000|";
Dictionary<string, string> dict = str.NameValuePairsToDictionary(":", "|");


    /// <summary>
    /// convert a string that consists of Name/Value Pairs to a Dictionary.
    /// Name and Value are separated by a given name/value separator
    /// Pairs are separated by a given pair separator token.
    /// example:
    /// Black:#00000|Green:#008000
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nvParis">string of name value pairs</param>
    /// <param name="nvSeparator">string that separates the name and value in a name value pair</param>
    /// <param name="pairSeparator">string that separates the name/value pairs from each other</param>
    /// <returns>Dictionary of Name value pairs as string,string</returns>
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> NameValuePairsToDictionary(this string nvPairs, string nvSeparator, string pairSeparator)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // default - "\n\r"
        // split name value pairs by separator
        string[] items = nvPairs.Split(pairSeparator.ToCharArray());

        // for each split item, split the name/value pair by 
        // pair separator to add a dictionary item
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            string[] keyVal = item.Split(nvSeparator.ToCharArray());
            if (keyVal.Length > 1)
                dict.Add(keyVal[0], keyVal[1]);
        }

        return dict;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
object settings = "Black:#00000|Green:#008000|";

var themeColors = (from setting in ((string)settings).Split('|')
                   where setting != ""
                   select setting.Split(new[]{':'}, 2))
                  .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```