# Add characters in dictionary

Tags: c#

In my program i have a piece of code which add characters in a dictionary

```
 var listOfSimilarCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 listOfSimilarCharacters.Add("l", "!");
 listOfSimilarCharacters.Add("1", "i");
 listOfSimilarCharacters.Add("O", "0");
 listOfSimilarCharacters.Add("o", "I");
```

But above in my code i have a property "SimilarCharacters" i need to reed this out and delete the four `listOfSimilarCharacters.Add` lines

```
/// <summary>
/// A constant that is lists all similar characters.
/// </summary>
public const string SimilarCharacters = "l!1iO0oI";
```

in some way i need to add the chars from `SimilarCharacters` in a dictionary and read the `SimilarCharacters` out so i can use this instead of the four lines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306767/linq-to-convert-a-string-to-a-dictionarystring-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection initializer to fill your dictionary:

```
var listOfSimilarCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
  { "l", "!" }, { "1", "i" }, {"O", "0"}, {"o", "I"} 
};
```

BTW why are you using strings to store chars?

Answer (score 0):

```
        string SimilarCharacters = "l!1iO0oI";

        var listOfSimilarCharacters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        bool timeToAdd = false;
        string key = String.Empty;
        string value = String.Empty;
        foreach ( var c in SimilarCharacters )
        {
            if ( timeToAdd )
            {
                value = c.ToString();
                listOfSimilarCharacters.Add( key, value );
            }
            else
            {
                key = c.ToString();
            }
            timeToAdd = !timeToAdd;
        }
```